# Can We run web connector as background process?

Tags: quickbooks

I want to run web connector as a background process on Remote Desktop Machine. Is it possible to run web connector when user is logged off?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to run web connector when user is logged off?

No.

Unfortunately, QuickBooks itself requires a GUI in order to function (even the API). It's just the way QuickBooks works.

Since no GUI is available if a user is not logged in, the Web Connector won't work.